# rvm use 1.9.2 leaves me using ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, rvm

I dont understand why after the rvm command I am still on ruby 1.8.7. Ive followed the install instructions for rvm and it all seemed to go fine - where do I look to start resolving this?

```
andrew@unifex:~$ rvm use 1.9.2 --default
Using /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
andrew@unifex:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]
andrew@unifex:~$

andrew@unifex:~$ rvm info

ruby-1.9.2-p290:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux unifex 2.6.22-3-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Nov 4 18:18:09 UTC 2007 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.1.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.9.2 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.2p290"
    date:         "2011-07-09"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2011-07-09 revision 32553"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290"
    ruby:         "/home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/andrew/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_20/bin:/usr/local/apache/maven/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_03/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290:/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290"
    IRBRC:        "/home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: What is the output of `which ruby` after running this command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this exact problem. It's down to your $PATH not being correct - /usr/bin/ruby is found before rvm gets a chance to do its thing.

In your ~/.bash_profile (As in /Users/andrew/.bash_profile) ensure you have this line present at the bottom of the file:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Then open a new shell

```
rvm reload
rvm use 1.9.2 --default
ruby -v
```

You should now have the correct version displayed.

Comment: Shouldn't the RVM line be at the end (to ensure nothing else is messing up the path)?

Comment: I'm not sure - I tried both and ended up with a very empty .bash_profile and this at the top.

Comment: "Shouldn't the RVM line be at the end (to ensure nothing else is messing up the path)? ", correct, it should be at the bottom. Per the docs, "Load RVM by appending the rvm function sourcing to your .bash_profile". Note that it is "appending". See the [installation docs](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install) for more info.